# Converting GeoTIFF to vector yields a very busy vector layer

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, vector, convert

I've been looking for a good way to convert GeoTIFF files to vector files. Specifically it is these files: https://data.jrc.ec.europa.eu/dataset/1d128b6c-a4ee-4858-9e34-6210707f3c81

I used QGIS to convert the GeoTIFF files to GPKG. It worked, but the vector layer is very busy, the conversion does not clearly define the pixels in the GeoTIFF file.

[image]

[image]

Is there a better way of doing this? Having polygons for each pixel would be fine, also a large multypolygon would be fine to. I would just like the algorithm to map the polygon correctly. The original file is a GeoTIFF comprised of 100x100m squares and in the vector layer there are slanted lines.

Comment: Please explain how did you convert the TIFF files into vectors and what is your aim. Do you want to convert each pixel into a small rectangular polygon?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, good point. I added more information to the original question.

Comment: Many polygons in the look pretty odd. The algorithm is turning each pixel into a rectangular polygon and then it makes an union from the adjacent polygons which have the same pixel value (DN). So every polygon should have only straight angles. It would be nice to have test data to play with.

Comment: I can't replicate this with one of the rasters from that set (floodmap_EFAS_RP020_C). I took a subset of that and I get nicely squared-off polygons that match neatly. I'm working with a roughly 2000x2000 subset just for speed. It looks like your polygons have had some smoothing applied to them which has cut off the corners. Are you sure you didn't run with any advanced parameters or do anything else to the vectors?

Comment: A possibility is that the polygons are fine, its just that QGIS is rendering them like this because you have a setting in the Settings... Options... Rendering panel maybe related to "Feature Simplification" or "Curve Segmentation" that is showing them this way.

Comment: It was the rendering, I used Folium in Python to render the map, I tried a different package and the polygon is fine. Thank you for the input, much appreciated.

Comment: You could also use the QGIS [Raster pixels to polygons](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgispixelstopolygons) tool instead of the [GDAL Polygonize](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterconversion.html#gdalpolygonize) tool.  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9akH.png)